# Huawei hotspot killing internet

Tags: huawei, wifi-hotspot

have a Huawei mobile phone. When I turn on the hotspot, I no longer have an internet connection on the phone itself. I've never had this problem on any other phone. I tried changing service providers and that didn't help. Is it specific to Huawei?

Comment: Probably you need to root your device and remove the crap.

Comment: Remove what crap?

Comment: Sorry, I've tried to say that it is clearly not an ordinary function of your phone. It is either a hardware problem, or you have some buggy apps. Android apps can manipulate your internet connections if you give them permission to do that; rooting or a factory reset could guarantee their elimination. I suspect, you can also first try a factory reset. I hope, maybe others might give you a hardware-specific and maybe better option as an answer.